# Swift Alert Action not working with segue

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, segue, alert

I'm working on a ForgotPassword Button this was no problem, if I click on it, it call performSegueWithIdentifier and opens a new ViewController. Now I have an Alert on Login if the credentials are wrong (wrong password) and I added a button to request password to call the ForgotPassword.

The problem is it calls the AlertAction correct, this calls the forgotPassword IBAction and the performSegue is also correctly called but the view won't appear.

```
// MARK: Actions
private func forgotPasswordAlertAction(action: UIAlertAction) {
    print("AlertRequestAction")
    forgotPassword(action)
}

@IBAction func forgotPassword(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("forgotPasswortAction")
    print(self)
    performSegueWithIdentifier(forgotPasswordId, sender: self)
}


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == forgotPasswordId,
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? AccountForgotPasswordViewController {
        print("forgotPasswortSegue")
        controller.emailFromInput = emailTextField.text
    }
}
```

[image: Segue from LoginController to ForgotPasswordController]

```
private func showError(error: AuthenticationError) {
    let title = NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: "Generic Title if an unkown error occured.")
    let message = NSLocalizedString("An Error occured. Please try again.", comment: "Generic Message if an unkown error occured.")

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Generic OK Button label"), style: .Default, handler: nil)

    switch error {
    case .BadCredentials:
        alertController.title = NSLocalizedString("Invalid Credentials", comment: "Title if provided credentials are invalid.")
        alertController.message = NSLocalizedString(
            "The entered credentials are invalid. Please try again with valid credentials or request a new password.",
            comment: "Generic Title if an unkown error occured.")


        let forgotPasswordAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: NSLocalizedString("Request Password", comment: "Request Password Button Label"), style: .Default, handler: forgotPasswordAlertAction)
        alertController.addAction(forgotPasswordAction)
    default:
        break
    }

    alertController.addAction(dismissAction)
    alertController.preferredAction = dismissAction
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You must be getting some statements regarding the animations being printed on your console isn't it ???

Comment: This is what i get on the Console:

Comment: AlertRequestAction
forgotPasswortAction
<MyApp.AccountLoginViewController: 0x7fdc158b73f0>
forgotPasswortSegue

Comment: Can you confirm your segues is bounded correctly in storyboard ???

Comment: Yes it is, it works for ne normal forgotPasswordButton

Comment: Picture is on the top i added it

Comment: Post the code where you create your `UIAlertController`

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can imagine in your case - that you are somehow moved from main queue when called alert. Confirm this by adding line `print(NSThread.isMainThread()` in your `forgotPasswordAlertAction(_:)` function. And if you will see `false` in console, then dispatch to main queue:

```
private func forgotPasswordAlertAction(action: UIAlertAction) {
    print("AlertRequestAction")
    print(NSThread.isMainThread())

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        self.forgotPassword(action)
    }
}
```

Comment: Post answer for us when you will find it, please.